# Python url и переменная из random

Tags: python, url

Народ, как переменную вставить из random?

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python2.7

import sys
import random
import urllib2
mood = random.randint(1000, 1200)
for i in xrange(10):
    f = urllib2.urlopen('http://site.com/analytics/', + 'mood', + '.html')
print f.read(1000)
```

Что-то не то творю ((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Замените предпоследнюю строчку на

```
f = urllib2.urlopen('http://site.com/analytics/' + str(mood) + '.html')
```